# Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 when attempt call ASP.NET controller

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc, angular, post, angular-services

I'm found and read many post about this error but don't found analogous or similar issues.
Attempt get data from MVC controller using post in angular 2.

Controller:

```
[RoutePrefix("")]
public class CategoryController : ApiController
{

    [HttpPost, Route("createNode")]
    public object CreateNode([FromBody]string nodeText)
    {
        return Json( new { nodeText = "test"});
    }
}
```

function in component

```
onclickCreateFolder(categoryName: string) {
    this.categoryService.createNode(categoryName).then(result => {
    });
```

angular-2 service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, RequestOptions, Request, RequestMethod, Headers  } from '@angular/http';
import { BaseService } from '../../base/base.service'
import { CategoryViewModel } from '../model/category-tree.model';
import { TreeNode } from 'primeng/primeng';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';



@Injectable()
export class CategoryTreeService {
    private apiUrl: string = '/';

    constructor(private baseService: BaseService, private http: Http) {
    }

    createNode(nodeText: string): Promise<any> {
        return this.baseService.post(this.apiUrl + "createNode", JSON.stringify({nodeText}));
    }
}
```

I am using base service. Here is a part that initiate post request:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Response, RequestOptionsArgs, ResponseContentType } from '@angular/http';
import { Http, RequestOptions, Request, RequestMethod, Headers } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class BaseService {
    private headers: Headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8', 'Data-Type': 'json' });

    constructor(private http: Http, private router: Router) {
    }

    public post<T>(url: string, body: any, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Promise<T> {
        return this.http.post(url, body, this.mergeHeaders(options))
            .toPromise()
            .then(response => response.json() as T)
            .catch(this.handleError.bind(this));
    }

    private mergeHeaders(options?: RequestOptionsArgs): RequestOptionsArgs {
        let args = options || {};
        args.headers = args.headers || this.headers;
        return args;
    }

    public handleError(error: any) {
        if (error.status == 400) {
            switch (error.statusText) {
                case "Authentication":
                    this.router.navigate(['/error/auth']);
                    break;
                default:
                    return Promise.reject(error);
            }
            return;
        }
        return Promise.reject(error.toString());
    }
}
```

I understand the reason for the error because in response i see my single html page. Also in debug i see that method in ASP.NET controller is not called. Maybe error in ASP.NET MVC routing? 
Already spent a lot of time, but I still do not understand where the error is. What i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Assumed the request header uses `Content-Type:application/json`, the error sounds returned from internal `JSON.parse` trying to parse response body which actually formed as HTML markups instead of JSON string. Use debugger to find out what `createNode` returns.

Comment: I use debugger and CreateNode in MVC controller is not invoked. Also i replaced `Content-Type:application/json` to `application/html` but saw JSON error again.